# Need to print data from an xml response in postman?This xml is a bit strange one

Tags: javascript, xml

1.I need to do api testing.
2.Here is the xml response given by the server.
3.I need to extract the data of partID,partBrand,quantityAvailable and store it 
  in an environment variable's and also print it in console.
4.I'm using Postman tool in chrome and used  java 
  script code to perform some tests.
5.Please provide a solution to extract data from this xml.

```
    <Reply 
     xmlns="">
     <productID>G500</productID>
     <ProductVariationInventoryArray>
     <ProductVariationInventory>
        <partID>B11007514</partID>
        <partDescription>g500 BLACK M</partDescription>
        <partBrand>Gildan</partBrand>
        <quantityAvailable>72105</quantityAvailable>
        <attributeColor>BLACK</attributeColor>
        <attributeSize>M</attributeSize>
        <validTimestamp>2017-11-23T05:31:39.689-05:00</validTimestamp>
    </ProductVariationInventory>
    </ProductVariationInventoryArray>
    </Reply>
```

Here is the code after converting it to json object using "xml2Json(responsebody)"

```
    {
  "Reply": {
    "productID": "G500",
    "ProductVariationInventoryArray": {
      "ProductVariationInventory": {
        "partID": "B11007514",
        "partDescription": "g500 BLACK M",
        "partBrand": "Gildan",
        "quantityAvailable": "72105",
        "attributeColor": "BLACK",
        "attributeSize": "M",
        "validTimestamp": "2017-11-23T05:31:39.689-05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now,I need to extract the data of partID,partBrand,quantityAvailable and store it in an environment variable's and also print it in console.

Comment: This question is very unclear! You do not even tell us the tool /language you want to use... Please show your own effort and te expected output.

Comment: Made modifications in my Question.Can you please provide a solution for it.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: please show some code! Show what you've tried so far...Where is your actual issue? StackOverflow is not a platform to let your work be done by someone else, but a forum to help people when they are stuck. *Can you please provide a solution for it* is a bit - uhm - brazen...

Comment: Btw: JavaScript and JSON are very closely related. Do some research on *JavaScript parse JSON to object* and you will find answers in seconds...

Comment: Thanks for you reply Shnugo. Got answer, just now.